# Is there a difference between a messenger and a prophet according to the Quran, Hadiths, or tradition?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad

I have now seen several articles now that use the terms synonymously but I saw a comment on a couple of the articles chastising the author for doing so? Is there a difference? If so, what is the difference?

Comment: Please be more clear, are you asking about "nebi" and "resul"?

Comment: @kalahari yes he's asking about nabi(prophet) and rasul(messenger).

Comment: @Kalahari Are there other interpretations that the Quran uses as messenger and prophet? Your answer could mean another question I have.

Comment: @JimmyG., Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

It is widely believed that "rasul" is a prophet who has been given books like Moses, Jesus and Mohammad(peace be upon all of them), and "nabi" is a prophet who hasn't been given books. But this is wrong according to some Turkish scholars. Here is their common answer:

**Nabi:** Comes from the root "nebe" which means news/message. Nabi is literally means who takes messages. For a religious term, who takes messages from Allah. Doesn't matter through angels or directly like Moses(puh) and Mohammad(puh).

**Rasul:** Comes from "risala" which means something which transfer (probably knowledge). Today, books are called risala. Thus rasul means someone who transfers the message taken from Allah to people.

In this context, every prophet is both nabi and rasul. First, they take the message, this is "nubuvvet". Then they deliver the message to the people, this is "risalet". For example Mohammad(puh) became nabi when the first verses came to him. He became rasul 3 years later, when he began to deliver the message.

You can think about a teacher. A teacher is always a teacher (like nabi), but he doesn't teach all the time (like rasul).

The scholars I mentioned also claims that in Quran, in the verses related with the Prophet(puh)'s personal issues, the word nabi is used, because the messages/warnings were for him. For example: **Surat At-Taĥrīm 66/1**:

> O Prophet, why do you prohibit [yourself from] what Allah has made lawful for you, seeking the approval of your wives? And Allah is Forgiving and Merciful. ([English translation](http://quran.com/66/1))
>
> Ya eyyuhen**nebi**yyu lime tuharrimu ma ehallellahu leke tebteğıy merdate ezvacike vallahu ğafurun rahıymun. ([Original Verse in Latin Alphabet](http://www.theholyquran.org/?x=s_main&y=s_middle&kid=4&sid=66))

Or **Surat Al-'Aĥzāb 33/59**:

> O Prophet, tell your wives and your daughters and the women of the believers to bring down over themselves [part] of their outer garments. That is more suitable that they will be known and not be abused. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful. ([English translation](http://quran.com/33/59))
>
> Ya eyyühen **nebi**yyü kul li ezvacike ve benatike ve nisail mü'minıne yüdnıne aleyhinne min celabıbihinn zalike edna ey yu'rafne fe la yü'zeyn ve kanellahü ğafurar rahıyma ([Original Verse in Latin Alphabet](http://www.theholyquran.org/?x=s_main&y=s_middle&kid=4&sid=33))

Lets look at **Surat Al-'A`rāf 7/157** for better understanding:

> Those who follow the Messenger, the unlettered prophet, whom they find written in what they have of the Torah and the Gospel, who enjoins upon them what is right and forbids them what is wrong and makes lawful for them the good things and prohibits for them the evil and relieves them of their burden and the shackles which were upon them. So they who have believed in him, honored him, supported him and followed the light which was sent down with him - it is those who will be the successful. ([Surat Al-'A`rāf 7/157](http://quran.com/7/157))
>
> Ellezıne yet**tebi**uner **rasul**en **nebi**yyel **ümmi**yyellezı yecidune mektuben ındehüm fit tevrati vel incıli ye'müruhüm bil ma'rufi ve yenhahüm anil münkeri ve yühıllü lehümüt tayyibati ve yüharrimü aleyhimül habaise ve yedau anhüm ısrahüm vel ağlalelletı kanet aleyhim fellezıne amenu bihı ve azzeruhü ve nesaruhü vetteveun nurallezı ünzile meahu ülaike hümül müflihun ([Original Verse in Latin Alphabet](http://www.theholyquran.org/?x=s_main&y=s_middle&kid=4&sid=7))

Please pay attention to the bold words. "tebi" means to dedicate yourself to someone, following his orders and footsteps. It is used with "rasul". "tebi to rasul" means following the rasul's orders and footsteps. "ümmi" means ignorant. This word is interpreted as "not knowing reading-writing", or "not knowing something generally". It is used with the word "nabi", "ümmi nabi" means unlettered prophet in English translation. Here you can see the difference if you look at the semantics of the verse. In this verse, emphasis is generally on the word rasul, it is in the center. And the rest of the verse is about his orders, laws, prohibitions etc. Nabi is used only in 1 adjective clause, in order to point that the Prophet(puh) hadn't any knowledge about the topic other than what was revealed to him.

I can give some video links for reference, but they are Turkish, also may not be counted as "proper reference".

Comment: If you are saying that messenger = prophet then [22:52](http://tanzil.net/#22:52) goes against it: "And We did not send before you any **messenger** or **prophet** except that when he spoke [or recited], Satan threw into it [some misunderstanding]...". 
_The way these words are used_ implies that they are two sets. There might be some overlapping but at least they are not equal.

Comment: @afnrf, I never said they are equal. Nabi is a permanent adjective. Rasul is more depend on time. While a prophet teaches, then in that time he becomes rasul. About 22:52, in the Arabic version, the "spoke/recite" part is actually **temenna** means wishing actually. It is translated into Turkish as "temenni etmek", wish. These Turkish scholars I mentioned before, also claim that some people like the mother of Moses(puh) is also a nabi, but neither a rasul, nor a prophet. She received some vahiy/inspiration only for herself, not to teach anyone.

Comment: @afnrf, Please look at these verses: [20/38](http://quran.com/20/38) and [28/7](http://quran.com/28/7). The Arabic word used here for inspiration is "evhayna", coming from the root vhy/ vahy/ revelation. Also, please look at this verse [42/52](http://quran.com/42/52). Here it is translated as revealed, because the verse is about Mohammad(puh). But the same word, evhayna. And the inspiration word in English translation is put only to emphasis the meaning. There is no actually a word for it. So, some people can be revealed other than prophets, and they become nabi. But not rasul.

Comment: @afnrf, To be clear, every prophet is both nabi and rasul; every rasul is also nabi, but not all nabi is rasul.

Comment: Interesting! I think [22:53](http://tanzil.net/#22:53) eliminates the possibility that أمنيته means `wishing (in one's mind)` here. Reason: "Satan tampered with it" and "God makes his suggestions a trial for those whose hearts are diseased or hardened". How can it be without `reciting it to the outside world`?

Comment: @afnrf, Actually [22/52-53](http://quran.com/22/52-53) say that the rasuls and nabis are human beings. Thus they shouldn't be turned into idols to worship. **22/52** says that like any person, when they wish something (in mind or in dua doesn't matter), Satan interferes to their wishes in order to corrupt them. But Allah fixes this situation. This means that, even the saints or prophets can be deceived by Satan. They are not perfect, they are human like us.

Comment: @afnrf, But because they fear Allah more than ordinary people, also they know the verses and Allah made them strong, Satan's delusions become useless. **22/53** is about other people. The saints and prophets saved themselves with the help of verses, the same trial is still there for other people. Satan whispers to everyone, and those who have disease or stone hearts follow this whispers. Because they think these are their wishes and they really want them, doesn't matter if they are proper wishes or not. Also Maryam(r.a), the mother of Jesus(puh) is a good example of the saints I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going for their literal meanings though.

Messenger - Is the one who's given scriptures by the creator. e.g. Prophets Moses, Muhammad(pb upon'em) etc.

Prophet - A person chosen by the creator to warn his community against the wrath of the creator and take them towards his mercy. e.g. Prophets Adam, Jesus, Moses, Muhammad (peace be on'em) etc.

Every messenger is a prophet, but not every prophet is a messenger.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: By this definition, would angels be prophets?

Comment: No, they're messengers(literal) to prophets(my view). e.g Angel Jibrael(Gabrel AS) was a messenger(literal) to many of the prophets.

Comment: Do your definitions have a basis in the Quran?

Comment: Yes @Mr.Bultitude do you want me to show, it might take a bit time...

Comment: Before I answer that, can you clear something else up for me? Are you saying that angels are messengers "literally" while not being messengers according to the definition you gave in the answer?

Comment: In Arabic, words mean based on the context. So, e.g Gabreal(peace) was a messenger(literal) who passed on the scriptures to the messengers(on whom the scriptures have been revealed). Beyond this I don't know. @Mr.Bultitude

Comment: @servantofWiser [91:13](http://tanzil.net/#91:13) calls Saleh a Rasul (Messenger) which apparently goes against your answer.

Comment: @afnrf even Jibrael (AS) is a [rasul](http://quran.com/81/19) But I said, no literal meaning.

Comment: @afnrf but kalahari's answer explains this better. OK.

Comment: @afnrf the same thing explained [What is the difference between NABI and RASUL?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-is-the-difference-between-nabi-and-rasul)

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude the same thing explained [What is the difference between NABI and RASUL?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-is-the-difference-between-nabi-and-rasul)

Answer (score 0):

salaams
yes, there is a difference:
every messenger wasa prophet, but not every prophet is a messenger ( i know it's a bit hard to take in)
A messenger was provided with a book to give to his people, like Moses, Issa, Mohammed,(peace be upon them all), etc i think there are around 25 messengers and prophets mentioned in the quran, but over 124000 prophets, each with the same message from god to bring his people back to the right path
i hope this helps :)

Comment: Also not all of 25 names in the Quran had been given books or papers.

Comment: @kalahari your right, i'm sorry, i should have mentioned that

Comment: @TashannaChamma [91:13](http://tanzil.net/#91:13) calls Saleh a Rasul (Messenger) which apparently goes against your answer

Comment: @afnrf how about you re-read my answer?

Comment: @TashannaChamma: Please help me understand if I missed something! Saleh was given not a book and Quran still calls him a Messenger. Therefore, having a book or not should not be a distinguishing factor.

Comment: @afnrf i' sorry, i just did some research and this is what i found. Yo're right, my answer is wrong

Comment: In 3:81 God defined the exact duty of the Prophet (Nabi) and also the duty of the Messenger (Rasoul):

"God took a covenant from the prophets, saying, "I will give you the scripture and wisdom. Afterwards, a messenger will come to confirm all existing scriptures. You shall believe in him and support him." He said, "Do you agree with this, and pledge to fulfil this covenant?" They said, "We agree." He said, "You have thus borne witness, and I bear witness along with you." 3:81

Comment: Verse 3:81, among many other verses, provides the definitions of "Nabi" (Prophet) and "Rasoul" (Messenger). "Nabi" is a messenger of God who delivers a new scripture, while "Rasoul" is a messenger commissioned by God to confirm existing scripture. Some messengers deliver a new scripture and in that case they are also prophets, but many other messengers do not deliver a new scripture. As a result, every "Nabi" is a "Rasoul," but not every "Rasoul" is a "Nabi".